# I am trying to assign an outlook task to another person, but the task just goes to me instead every time

Tags: outlook, task, userform, assign

I am a complete novice with coding and have scoured sites for how to do things and cobbled together some code to create an outlook task from a userform I created for tracking workload requests.
I have the team members all listed as categories in our team mailbox, so added this to the form to make identifying the assigned person simpler, but wanted the tasks to go into our shared mailbox rather than the individual assigned. I have tried manually inputting the mailbox address and including it in a cell in the workbook and called out to that, but each time the task only comes to me

This is the code I have for the 'Create Task and Submit' on the userform to add the info to the excel workbook and to create the outlook task:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add("mailbox@mycompany.com")
    myRecipient.Type = olTo
    myRecipient.Resolve
If myRecipient.Resolved Then
With OutTask
    .Subject = Programme
    .DueDate = DueDate
    .Status = 1
    .Importance = 1
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderTime = DueDate
    .Categories = Contact
    .Body = SubDetails
    .Save   
End With
End If
Set OutTask = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Workload")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If Trim(Me.Programme.Value) = "" Then
Me.Programme.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please enter Programme"
Exit Sub
End If


With ws
'
.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.Programme.Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.SubType.Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.SubDetails.Value
.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.DueDate.Value
.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.Contact.Value
.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.RegContact.Value
'
End With

Me.Programme.Value = ""
Me.SubType.Value = ""
Me.SubDetails.Value = ""
Me.DueDate.Value = ""
Me.Contact.Value = ""
Me.RegContact.Value = ""
Me.Programme.SetFocus
```

End Sub

I am more than sure there is likely a simpler way round this, but the above works exactly as I wanted other than where the task goes. Anybody able to point out where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance